# All but one objects not visible, yet in library, rendering. Alt+H doesnt work

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Help!

I've probably used some shortkey than hide all objects but the one selected, and then saved blender file and quit. Now, i don't remember what it was and im wasting time to "unhide" them.

The thing is they're not hidden, as ALT+H doesnt work.
Tried Clear All Restrict Render but it's even not that, because all objects are:
- rendering
- visible, selectable IN LIBRARY
- do have eye sign toggled on

I just cant unhide them.

Help?

Comment: @Jackey Sawicki, try uploading the blend file. If you don't know how to upload the blend file, then go to meta stackexchange and there's already an answer there

Comment: that would be more informative, I think

Comment: http://www.studioaurora.pl/download/sudafed_pos_zima_ulotkownik.blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Go to object mode select one object and press <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> a couple of times(2-3)

Comment: It just hides the only visible object.

Comment: @JacekSawicki can you find the invisible object in the outliner? Also i re-edited the answer

Comment: All objects are visible as layers in outliner. All have eye icon visible (active).

Comment: Lol, as a former programmer i've ignored "/" sign and pressed "a" couple of times ;)

Comment: @xlxs tp make this a better answer please explain what the function of the proposed key is...

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're in local view. You can tell by looking in the top left corner of your viewport, it says something like User Perspective (Local). As xlxs said, you can use / to switch local view on or off. But be sure to use the one on the keypad. The regular one doesn't work.

It could also be that you moved the other objects to a different layer.
Below your viewports there are two 5 by 2 grids. If there are dots in a square it means there are objects on that layer. You can either show multiple layers at the same time by shift left clicking the grid squares and making them visible (the squares turn dark), or you can left click a square to only show that layer. If you select objects in a certain layer and press m, you can move them to another layer.

Comment: I only work on 1 layer, as my projects are far too less complicated to work on more.

Local/Global doesnt change anything.

Im 100% sure it's a shortcut. Because i was showing some people that i accidentially found how you can hide all objects besides the one i have selected.

Comment: Are the other objects still in the Outliner? The Outliner is the list with all the objects in your file. It's on the top right by default. By default it shows your scene and inside there are Render Layers, World and all of the objects in your scene.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, press <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> (and switch first to 3D view, because your blend is in UV view). If shortcut is not working, try View->View Global/Local. I did that and I can see all objects now. So, do99 and xlxs are right, it is about local/global view. Besides, you do have two layers, one with wall and furniture, another with monitor and some trash can. Switch to Object mode and you should see these layers too.